# How to morph a plus sign to a minus sign using CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-transitions

I want to create a toggle `button` that morphs its shape from a plus sign to a minus sign.

**Using CSS only**, ***without* the use of pseudo-elements**.

My **desired effect** is to have the vertical line in the "+" sign to shrink into the horizontal line.

I know it's possible but I'm not sure which is the best route to take. I was thinking of doing something with the `height` but I'm worried about the `line-height` of browsers changing its position in the element.

```js
$('button').on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
button {
color: #ecf0f1;
background:  #e74c3c;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  }
button span {
  transition: all .75s ease-in-out;
  }
button.active span {
  /* Code to morph + to - */
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button><span>+</span></button>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because of the simplicity of the shapes, the easiest way is just to make the `+` and `-` with elements. Using pseudo elements would be the cleanest solution, but you can also just use a DOM element and have a slightly messier document structure.

With that in mind, the actual solution is straightforward. We use CSS to position elements to resemble the desired characters, and then "morph" between them by animating that position.

Take a look over the following code, and try to understand what each rule is accomplishing.

```css
button {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  background: #e74c3c;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}

button span {
  position: absolute;
  transition: 300ms;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Create the "+" shape by positioning the spans absolutely */
button span:first-child {
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  width: 10%;
  left: 45%;
}

button span:last-child {
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  height: 10%;
  top: 45%;
}

/* Morph the shape when the button is hovered over */
button:hover span {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

button:hover span:last-child {
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</button>
```

Comment: yup the easiest but OP doesn't want pseudo elements :/

Comment: @dippas I'll update the answer, but it is still the same concept.

Answer (score 18):

> Note : please stop editing the question making the answers incorrect

### CSS solution

```js
$('button').on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
button {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  background: #e74c3c;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.plus,
.minus {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .5s all ease-out;
}
.plus {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
button.active .plus {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.minus {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
button.active .minus {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button>
  <span class="plus"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
  <span class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span>
</button>
```

### A (old) CSS solution:

Using pseudo element `::before` with `content` property

```js
$('button').on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
button {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  background: #e74c3c;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
button span {
  transition: all .75s ease-in-out;
  position:relative
}
button span::before {
  content:"+"
}
button.active span::before {
  content:"-"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button><span></span></button>
```

### A (old) jquery Solution:

no need for `span`, you can do this using `text()` with a if statement in jquery

```js
$('button').on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).text() == "+" ? $(this).text("-") : $(this).text("+");
});
```

```css
button {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  background: #e74c3c;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  transition: all .75s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>+</button>
```

Comment: I want it to morph, not just change. Thanks!

Comment: just FYI I added a CSS only solution, what you mean by morph?

Comment: please stop editing the question making the answers incorrect

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better. I already mentioned it in the description of my question. I want the vertical line in the plus sign to shrink until it disappears, and it becomes a minus sign.

Comment: Updated the answer with CSS only solution with no jQuery, no pseudo elements

Comment: Elegant solution +1

Answer (score 2):

> Ah my bad I've overlooked that OP doesn't want to use any pseudo
>   elements. But the big advantage with pseudo elements would be that you have less HTML Code and a cleaner structure.
>
> It's also a different *morphing* animation as OP wants but maybe someone else can use this.
>
> So if you don't mind I'll let my suggestion there.

Maybe something like this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="button"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #343838;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background: #70975B;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 1.1);
}

.button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 2px;
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
}

.button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  background: white;
}

.button.clicked {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  background: #CC2A41;
}

.button.clicked:before {
  width: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

And here a working example
http://codepen.io/svelts/pen/LkyZoZ

Answer (score 1):

I figured after writing this as I needed one, I would show an example with multiple transforms happening at once to give it a "polished" look.

I also added a "click" event to keep the cross clicked.

```css
    .toggleIcon {
        position: relative;
        width: 50px; /* Define the size of your toggle icon */
        height: 50px;
        background: #ffffff; /* Set the background color */
        border-radius: 50%; /* Make it round */
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .toggleIcon::after,
    .toggleIcon::before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        height: 30px;
        width: 2px;
        background: #1A0D07;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transition: transform 0.4s ease;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .toggleIcon.toggleActive::before {
        transition: transform 0.2s ease;
    }

    .toggleIcon::before {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
    }

    .toggleIconParent:hover .toggleIcon::before,
    .toggleIcon:hover::before,
    .toggleIcon:active::before{
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg) scale(1.2);
    }

    .toggleIcon:hover::after,
    .toggleIconParent:hover .toggleIcon::after,
    .toggleIcon:active::after,
    .toggleIcon.toggleActive::after {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg) scale(1.2);
    }

    .toggleIcon.toggleActive::before {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg) scale(1.2);
    }

    .toggleIcon.toggleActive::after,
    .toggleIcon.toggleActive::before {
        width: 1px;
    }
```

```html
<span <span onclick="this.classList.toggle('toggleActive');" class="toggleIcon h-8 w-8 cursor-pointer relative"></span>
```

Answer (score -3):

try this

```js
$('button').on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass('toggle');
  if ($this.hasClass('toggle')) {
    $this.text('+');
  } else {
    $this.text('-');
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  background: #e74c3c;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  transition: all .75s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">+</button>
```

Comment: I want it to morph, not just change. Thanks!